# What are the different step types in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm currently studiying Spring Batch and I don't get the difference between different **steps types**: chunk-oriented, item-oriented, stadalone...etc. I'm not even sure if these are actually steps types...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really only two major "step types" in Spring Batch.

## [Chunk-Oriented Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing)

This step consists of a reader->processor->writer combination (where the processor is optional). This is the most common type of Batch step.

## [Tasklet Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep)

This step does not have a reader, processor, or writer but instead is simply a task to be executed. It is useful for running single command-like processes in your batch job (for example, to invoke a stored procedure on a database).

---

Technically speaking a chunk-oriented step is a sub-type of a Tasklet step. Also, there are different configurations of a chunk-oriented step that has different behavior. Like parallel step, partitioned step, mutli-threaded step, etc... but these are all more advanced concepts that build on top of the basics mentioned above. Understand chunk-oriented step first; then explore the more advanced configurations.

Comment: Ok, thank you FGreg for your response, one more question please : does the chunk-oriented step necessarily have a reader and writer ?

Comment: I see. Thank you @FGreg for your response and clarifications:)